# How to consume entire View with Stackview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, constraints, uistackview

I have a this hierarchy:

View > Stackview > Tableview

The Stackview has these constraints:
- Trailing Space to: Superview
- Leading Space to: Superview

The Tableview has these constraints to the Stackview:
- Trailing Space to: Superview
- Leading Space to: Superview

The underlying class is a UIViewController.  I get a tableview that looks like this:

[image]

Notice all of the right/left margin. Is there a way to get rid of the margins?

Comment: View Controller embedded inside navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Interface Builder constrains your views to `margin`s, not the actual view bounds. 
Select your constraints (one by one), and go to the inspector view on the right, where you can control how the constraint is set up (like trailing <- > leading, bottom <-> top etc). Here, unselect `Relative to margin`.

[image: XCODE IB MARGINS]

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` separators don't span the entire cell; that's just how they are styled. If you, for instance, check the table view in the inspector, or set a background color on it, you should find that the tableview does in fact take up the whole space.